# General Link Field Reuse with Multisite

Tags: sxa, multisite

I have a Sitecore 10 SXA multisite setup that uses delegated areas. Each delegated page (item) contains several promos with datasources set to the main site. Within these promos we have internal links to various delegated items shared to all sites. I want these promos locked down but would like to have the internal general link field in the promo not link back to the main site. Instead, it should be aware of site context and stay within the current site.

My original thought was some $site token in the general link field but I'm assuming there is a better method. I imagine this is a common multisite question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by using a Scriban variant with the promos. With  `IGenerateScribanContextProcessor` I was able to point each action link to the appropriate site. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the source query `query:$linkableHomes` for all the linkable sites.

More information:

- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/the-sxa-pipelines.html
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/adjust-link-settings-to-enable-cross-site-linking.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think this will fulfill my need. That token allows users to select the linkable item from the various sites. My promos all live under a main site with the link set there. It needs to dynamically set the site name. The promos are shared to the other sites through the datasources of the cloned page. I don't want to copy them to the other sites.

Example Link in Promo: /Tenant/MainSite/Home/About Us


Needs to be: /Tenant/$site/Home/About Us